# Is there a way to output a value with the higher number of instances?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I'm using MySQL and I'm having trouble trying to output a list of places based on it's rating.

I am trying to output a table with a single column (place) that has the names of places that have **more** good ratings than bad ratings.

Here is my ratings table:

```
CREATE TABLE ratings (
   ID int
   place varchar(255)
   opinion varchar(255)
);
```

And here is the data inside it:

```
id | place  | opinion
---+--------+--------
1  |Fiji    |Good 
2  |Fiji    |Not good 
3  |Canada  |Good 
4  |Canada  |Good
5  |Canada  |Good
6  |France  |Good
7  |France  |Not good
8  |Russia  |Not good
9  |Laos    |Good
```

My query should return something like this:

```
place
-------
Canada
```

So far I'm stumped. I feel that I should somehow compare the ratings column using count, but I'm not quite experienced in SQL yet. Can anybody help please?

Comment: You need weights for each rating, so you can do calculate average score. Like: good + not good / 2

Comment: Hi Shah. O. Jones already gave a perfect answer, but I would like to point your attention to the database design itself. To me this looks pretty poor. Would it not make more sense to have 3 columns: place (varchar), good_opinion_cnt (int), bad_opinion_cnt (int). Then allow each place only once in the table and add opinions as increments to the counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for IF, and SUM, and GROUP BY. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qJzieGghoAr1u98cRQ3mBU/0)

```
SELECT place
  FROM rating
 GROUP BY place
 HAVING SUM(IF(opinion = 'Good',1,-1)) > 0
```

The expression `IF(opinion = 'Good',1,-1)` gives either 1 or -1 depending on the text of the rating column.  Summing them up gives the overall goods minus bads. Putting all that in the HAVING clause with a `> 0` filter captures only the ones with a net positive "good" score.

It's worth your trouble to study IF, SUM, COUNT, and GROUP BY carefully. They are very important parts of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you could use count and group  by and limit 1  order by count desc

```
select place 
from my_table  
where opinion  ='good'
group by place 
order by count(*) desc 
limit 1
```

or using a rating   based on good / Not good

```
select place 
from my_table  
group by place 
order by sum(case when opinion ='good' then 1 when opinion='Not good' then -1 end) desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: Cmon man it's not about only count but the value of the rating

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this database design won't really work well on real data. How can you evaluate opinions because it is natural language. For example, what are differences between "This is good but too expensive". "This is not so good but I love culture ...".

So you must provide a way more quantitative to evaluate. I propose add a column named "rating" from 1 star to 5 star. (and 5 is the best).

```
CREATE TABLE ratings (
   ID int
   place varchar(255)
   opinion varchar(255)
   rating int
);
```

After you have this design, we continue to question: what is the best place ?

- it can be the place with the most 5-star ratings.
- it is the highest average rating. e.g: 3.5 rating over 3.0 rating.
- ...

Defined this metric is hard, and depends on metric, we will have respectively solution. Some solution can be implemented using SQL, some solution must use pipeline (e.g: a job queue to do some complicated tasks for rating).

Comment: Well, we can evaluate 'good' and 'not good' without too much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
SELECT place
    FROM ratings
    GROUP BY place ORDER BY COUNT(opinion) DESC LIMIT 1
```

i hope it will help.